# Study convergence of integral $\alpha$ according to parameter $\alpha$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

We have $I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x-1}{x^\alpha-1}dx$, and the problem asks to study convergence of $I$ according to values of $\alpha$.

Comment: I think it must be $\alpha>0$$

Answer (score 1):

It is not defined for $\alpha =0$ and it is convergent for all $\alpha \neq 0$. For justification look at the limiting values of the integrand as $x \to 0$ and $x \to 1$. [Use L'Hopital's Rule].